# CDATA in XML with ]] in the content

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I am using vtd-xml to do some xpaths on XML. My XML contains CDATA tags which vtd-xml seems to have an issue parsing.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><![CDATA[ some random ]] stuff ]]></root>
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
Caused by: com.ximpleware.ParseException: Error in CDATA: Invalid termination sequence
Line Number: 2 Offset: 30
    at com.ximpleware.VTDGen.process_cdata(VTDGen.java:3092)
    at com.ximpleware.VTDGen.parse(VTDGen.java:2640)
    at sandpit.lib.xml.VtdXmlDocument.from(VtdXmlDocument.java:132)
    ... 7 more
```

Is this a bug in vtd-xml or is my XML invalid?

Comment: It's a bug, I would say. All resources I could google in the last 5 mins say "]]" is ok for content. Anyway - that won't help you much to overcome the issue.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author is usually pretty active. Last time I reported a bug, a fix was presented pretty quickly

Comment: I'd give it a shot then. Even if there is no quick fix, maybe they can tell you a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been reported and fixed I believe. Check out the latest vtdGen.java from CVS and do a build.

Comment: Ah thats a shame, perhaps someone from the community has uploaded on your behalf: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ximpleware/vtd-xml/2.13